# How to scroll to top after ajax request within iframe?

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following **jQuery** code in an **iframe**:

```
<script>
jQuery("#logBtn").click(function(){
    jQuery("#content-promo").load("/path/to/file.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
      if (status == "error") {
      var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
      $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      }else{ //update
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
      }
    });

    return false;
});
</script>
```

How can the iframe scroll back to the top after the AJAX-request?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I've added the code below to `file.php` and it works now.

`<script> window.parent.parent.scrollTo( 0, 800 ); </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('#my-frame').scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code `window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);`

where

```
Parameters    
    * x-coord is the pixel along the horizontal axis.
    * y-coord is the pixel along the vertical axis.
```